# Android - BaseAdapter - XML, ListView, Button

Tags: android, xml, listview, baseadapter

I'm an iOS developer making the jump to Android to port a project I'm working on and I appear to be failing to grasp a few concepts on Android's custom BaseAdapter. I'm working on an app that parses XML from a site and populates the text from the XML elements into a ListView. I have the XML parsing portion down with no problem. The problem I run into is with adding a button to each row in the list view. I understand the concept of setting the OnClick Listener and that I need to implement a BaseAdapter, but I can't seem to get my data from my main activity to the class I have setup that contains my BaseAdapter. Right now the data does not show up when the app is launched. I've performed some debugging and verified that the data from the menuItems ArrayList is sent properly to the BaseAdapter class, I'm just not getting how to get it displayed in the ListView. It's probably something really small I think I've just looked at it for too long and am not seeing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code and layout XML is listed below.

```
public class Podcasts extends ListActivity{

private static final String HASHMAP_ID = "_id";
private CustomAdapter adap;

static final String URL = "http://www.undignified.podbean.com/feed";

//XML Node Keys
static final String KEY_ITEM  = "item";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "itunes:subtitle";
static final String KEY_PODCASTURL = "enclosure";

public static final  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

    setContentView(R.layout.podcasts); 


    //Instance of XML parser
    UndigParser uparser = new UndigParser();

    String xml = uparser.getXmlFromURL(URL);        

    Document doc = uparser.getDomElement(xml);    

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    for(int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);


        map.put(KEY_TITLE, uparser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
        map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, uparser.getValue(e, KEY_DESCRIPTION));
        map.put(KEY_PODCASTURL, uparser.getValue(e, KEY_PODCASTURL));



        menuItems.add(map);
    }

     adap = new CustomAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_PODCASTURL}, new int[]{ R.id.title, R.id.description, R.id.podcasturl});
    //adap = new CustomAdapter(this, menuItems);

    setListAdapter(adap);


public static class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems, int listItem, String[] strings, int[] is){

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.description=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.podcasturl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.podcasturl);
            holder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.downloadBTN=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnStartDownload);

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Text-" + String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            holder.downloadBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                private int pos = position;

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Button-"+String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView description;
        TextView title;
        TextView podcasturl;
        Button downloadBTN;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Currently set to zero. If I set it to menuItems.size() it will crash the app.
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        return null;
    }
}
```

XML layout - list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dip">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/startPodcastDownload"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:text="Download Podcast"> 
</Button>        


</LinearLayout>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/podcasturl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

Also make these changes:

```
adap = new CustomAdapter(this, menuItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_PODCASTURL}, new int[]{ R.id.title, R.id.description, R.id.podcasturl});
```

to:

```
adap = new CustomAdapter(YourActivityName.this, menuItems);
```

and Create Adapter's constructor as:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems)
```

You have defined count of the adapter as 0,so how will get any value in the list.Your app crashes,its ok but you must be getting `Log's` of that error.just paste that errors here whether the list you are getting is null or what for that you must be getting `NullPointerException` in that you must be getting some another error.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've made the changes you listed above and and it is a NullPointerException:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at tv.undignified.android.Podcasts$CustomAdapter.getView(Podcasts.java:150)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)

Comment: Changes have been made. Still receiving the exact same error. It almost seems like it cannot get the size of menuItems?

Comment: in getCount() try to see what is size of menuItems by Log.d("size",""+menuItems.size());

Comment: It says it's 20, which is accurate with the amount of items that should be there.

Comment: so there is no issue of empty arraylist.now see that whatever you have defined have initialized each and every thing properly.Null pointer also comes when you have not initialized any object.